# Update-assignment of `empty` only deletes first path

Tags: jq

As far as I can understand from the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Update-assignment%3A%7C%3D), update-assignment (`|=`) is supposed to assign the RHS to every path on the LHS, and if the RHS is `empty` it should delete the path. But as seen below, it only deletes the first path, while `del` and update-assignment of a plain value do update all the paths.

```
$ jq --version
jq-1.6
$ echo '[1, 2]' | jq -c 'del(.[])'
[]
$ echo '[1, 2]' | jq -c '.[] |= 0'
[0,0]
$ echo '[1, 2]' | jq -c '.[] |= empty'
[2]
```

What did I miss, or is it a bug I should report? (I did check related issues here as well as jq's bugtracker, but only found issues relating to `try`/`catch`).

Comment: It's a bug, and it has already been [reported](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2051).

Comment: You could switch to [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq) (a Go rewrite of jq) which works well on this issue.

Comment: @pmf, clearly my search-foo was weak. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it is indeed a [bug](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2051) (thanks @pmf), and the workaround of using `del` works just fine (as I showed in the question). (The syntax for `del` also fixes evaluation order, which I tend to get wrong in the `|=` syntax -- `|=` binds tighter than `|`, so adding a something like `| select(...)` on the RHS needs parentheses).